# is there anyway to check if $parent exists in vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Sometimes I get an error like:

> TypeError: this.$parent.test() is not a function

Here is my method in parent:

```
test() {
  console.log('test')
}
```

And here is the child:

```
...
if (this.$parent) {
  this.$parent.test()
}
```

I know theres another way to do this, but what I want to know is if I can check if that parent exists!! Is that possible in vue.js?? Thanks

Comment: Is your end goal to check if the parent exists or to call a method on the parent?

Comment: `if (this.$parent && typeof this.$parent.test === 'function') {` would be the "safe" way, but not the recommended way for a child to "communicate" with parent in vue

Comment: The message `TypeError: this.$parent.test() is not a function` does not indicate that the parent doesn't exist. You'd get a different error for that. That error indicates that `this.$parent` does exist but the property `test` is not a function. Chances are it is `undefined`. Most likely your parent is just not the component you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of calling parent's methods is to emit an event and to  handle this in the parent. if the parent method does not exist you will have a template compile time error (good for debugging).

In the parent template:

```
<my-component @myevent="test"></my-component>
```

The the child component:

```
this.$emit('myevent');
```

This is done to decouple the parent from the component and to enable re-use.

IMHO, you should have a good reason not to do this way, in this case, your solution is ok.